# Any Raspberry Pi alternative that DOES work with HDMI auto-switch?

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi, odroid, orange-pi

Are there any computers that don't cost much more than Raspberry Pi 3, but unlike it, CAN be used with an HDMI auto-switch?
The Raspberry Pi is an "always-on" computer, so auto-sensing doesn't work with it. 
I don't know if that is also the case with alternatives such as Orange Pi or Odroid C2.
And what if I powered the Raspberry Pi from a powered USB hub instead of directly from the wall, would that make a difference???
Thank you

Comment: You probably want to ask this on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ (but read their help first as this question may also be off-topic there).

Comment: I agree with Wai Ha Lee, but perhaps you could rephrase your question into one asking about what configuration is needed for the RPi to work with an HDMI auto-switch.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll do that

Comment: You can look into Arduino, pretty sure you can accomplish that using it.

Comment: Thank you Cillian but I need an actual computer which can run software (e.g. Kodi) and if I understand correctly Arduino is not like that.